# Python Selenium - Scrape cell data from table

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm scraping data from Yahoo Finance and trying to get scrape a particular piece of data from a cell. Specifically, the Total Revenue 2019-12-31 for Apple: https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL

This is the xpath file I wrote, expect whenever I run it, it throws an error `Unable to locate element` error.

`revenues = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[@class="Ta(c)"]')[2].text`

Would anyone kindly help me identify the error in the xpath directory which I wrote above, which makes it unable to locate the particular element?

Appreciate any help here!

Answer (score 0):

It may be incorrect locator. You can try as follows:

```
revenues = browser.find_element_by_xpath('(((//*[@data-reactid="30"])[6]/div/div)[2]/div/div)[3]/span').text
```

Answer (score 0):

See you are using

```
revenues = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[@class="Ta(c)"]')[2].text
```

it's wrong. since `find_element_by_xpath` returns a single web element so you can not do [2], use `find_elements_by_xpath` instead in case you want to return a list of web element, and then you can simply use indices `[2]` on that.

Now, I think your xpath also need a tweak, try  below :

```
revenues = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Total Revenue']/ancestor::div[@title='Total Revenue']/../following-sibling::div[3]/span").text
print(revenues)
```

should get you `260,174,000`